# java.lang.NullPointerException is displayed while executing TestNg.xml file in selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, xml, selenium, webdriver

I am new to Selenium WebDriver.

Prog:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class sample1 
{
    @BeforeMethod
    public void BeforeMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("This is Before Method");
    }
    @Test
    public void f1()
    {
        System.out.println("This is f1 method");
    }
    @Test
    public void f2()
    {
        System.out.println("This is f2 Method");
    }
}
```

TestNG XML File:

```
<suite name="s1">
    <test name="t1">
        <Classes>
            <Class name="sample1" />
            <methods>
                <include name= "f1" />
                <include name= "f2" />
            </methods
        </Classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

While executing the above xml file Java Null pointer error is displayed.

Can any one please help me.

Here is the Exeception getting:

`org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:341)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.xmlMethod(TestNGContentHandler.java:456)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.endElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:690)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown     Source)
    at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknow    n Source)
    at             com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver    .next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown     Source)
    at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
    ... 3 more`

Thanks & Regards

I have changed the capital letters in the Tag names to small letters, Then i am getting the below exception:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: ChangePage
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:543)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown     Source)
    at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown     Source)
    at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unkn    own Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: Can you add exception trace?

Comment: You are missing `>` after `</methods` (not sure it is relevant though)

Comment: Added Exception log. Please take a look.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl '>' after '</method' is added in the code. Typing mistake. Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change class name to correct format: `Sample1` and make sure that file name is `Sample1.java`.

XML should be:

```
<suite name="s1">
    <test name="t1">
        <Classes>
            <Class name="Sample1" />
        </Classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

TestNG automatically detect test methods because You annotated them :) .

Comment: Result:
s1
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

No exception displayed. But no methods executed.

Comment: maybe configuration with your testNG is wrong. change Make chapter 2 from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_tutorial.pdf

Comment: I have installed TestNG from eclipse. So i haven't set the "TESTING_HOME" envinorment variable.
But in the tutorial, they installed it manually by downloading it from www.TestNg.org . 
Do i also need to set "TESING_HOME" path?
If Yes, where TestNG will get installed in eclipse folder?
Note: Executing TestNG prog, directly is working Fine. Only executing TestNG.xml file is throwing exception.

Comment: Updated my question. Can u please take a look at it.

Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

Classes tag and class tag should be upper case.
I tried this, its solved.

Answer (score -2):

Please change the `<Classes>` tag to `<classes>` and `<Class>` to `<class>`

The tags should be Lower cases